# What are .Plo files and how are they used by the source code and GNU Autotools?

Tags: c++, autotools, autoconf, automake

I am relatively new to C++ coding. I have a repository of C++ source code which along with the rest of the `.h`, `.cpp`, `configure` and `Makefiles` has many `.Plo` files. What are `.Plo` files and how are they used by the source code, the configure script and the Makefile?

P.S.: Reading the contents of a `.Plo` file gives me a list of scripts as follows:

```
libxcam_ocl_la-cl_blender.lo: cl_blender.cpp /usr/include/stdc-predef.h \
 cl_blender.h ../../xcore/xcam_std.h ../../config.h \
 ../../xcore/base/xcam_common.h /usr/include/string.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h \
 /usr/include/features.h /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/long-double.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-64.h \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/stddef.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/locale_t.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/__locale_t.h \
 /usr/include/strings.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/strings_fortified.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h \
 /usr/include/stdio.h /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/typesizes.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/__FILE.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/FILE.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libio.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/_G_config.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/__mbstate_t.h \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/stdarg.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio_lim.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sys_errlist.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/stdint.h /usr/include/stdint.h \
```

I also have `.po` (portable object) files in this repo which have similar content. How do they differ from `.Plo` files?

Comment: Looks like these are intermediate files generated by libtool. You can safely ignore them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am relatively new to C++ coding. I have a repository of C++ source code which along with the rest of the `.h`, `.cpp`, `configure` and `Makefiles` has many `.Plo` files. What are `.Plo` files and how are they used by the source code, the configure script and the Makefile?

`.Plo` files are generated outputs of an Automake- and libtool-based build system, which record information determined at compile time about dependencies of your various object files on header files.  They are used on subsequent builds to help `make` recognize when previously-built object files have been obsoleted by header modifications.  Dummy versions are generated by `configure`.  Their content is (re)generated from the source and header files as a side effect of compilation, and referenced by the Autotools-generated makefiles.

As compile-time generated files, these are not usually placed under source control or included in source distribution packages, so if that's what you mean by "repository" then your situation is a bit odd.

> Upon looking it up, I get results saying that this file format is used by HP Graphics Language Plotter files (which I'm not sure what the .Plo files in my repo are), but I don't understand how these files tie in with the rest of my code.

That's an altogether unrelated file format.

Comment: Thanks for that. I wasn't very clear, I guess, but my .Plo files didn't come with my source code, I got them after running the configure script.